# Combining two PHP sql statements into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm after a little help in the quest for cleaner code...

Current code which is working fine. Wondering if I can make it into one SQL statement as opposed to two...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_a (1,2,3,4) VALUES ('$1','$2','$3','$4');";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$mysql_link);

$id = mysql_insert_id();

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO table_b (1,2,3,4) VALUES ('$id','$5','$6','$7');";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2,$mysql_link);
```

How can I combine these two to work within my current php script?

Thanks!

Comment: these are two separate DML statements which couldn't becombined

Comment: Yup, can't combine multiple `INSERT` statements.

Comment: @alex: on the same table he can combine

Comment: Sorry, should have specified I was talking about this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An insert in two different tables is not possible.
If you want to reduce your query count you may have to reconsider your database structure.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, you can't combine them, because inserts are in 2 different tables, although you could write a stored procedure (with necessary parameters) containing both of these queries and call that procedure in PHP instead of writting those statements... It would help to tell the reason you want to do that, because i can't understand if you want to get more compact (reusable) code, or improve the performance of your DB...

Answer (score 1):

When I see another question of this kind, I am always wondering, why noone asks how to combine ALL sql queries of the script into one. All SELECTs, INSERTS, UPDATES. Wouldn't it be logically?

What's the strange desire to combine? What's the point in it? What's wrong in 2 separate queries?

When you eat, do you mix a salad, a soup, a main dish, a drink into one bowl and then consume it? No? Why do you want to put all the queries into same bowl then?